# htaccess - How to enable uppercase letters in URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.120
RewriteRule ^phpinformation.php /info.php [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^phpinformation /info.php [R,NC,L]
RewriteBase /
## hide .php extension # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

This hides `.php` extension, as well as redirecting from `http://192.168.1.120/phpinformation` (URL that doesn't exist) to existing `http://192.168.1.120/info` URL.

I want to be able to call these URLs with uppercases as well as with lowercases: `PHPINFORMATION,INFO,PHPINFORMATION.PHP,INFO.PHP`.

How to modify this code to enable uppercase URL calls?

Comment: That is not that easily possible, at least not if you are on an OS that has a case-sensitive file system. Why would you want this anyway? You should rather have _one_ URL for this to begin with, and at most redirect other versions to the correctly spelled version. The latter I would probably do in a 404 handler script - because then you have the full functionality of PHP available to check whether a differently “cased” version of the file actually exists.

Comment: I though  that is easy by using [NC] flags. Is it possible that way?

Comment: If not, then what is the use of [NC] flag?

Comment: No, the NC flag specifies whether a check via a regular expression should match regardless of case - that’s on a string/text level. You however would need to have `PHPINFORMATION.PHP` “translated” to `phpinformation` to make it find the existing file. Although you could achieve this with a [mapping function in a RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#mapfunc), this is not configurable in .htaccess, you would need access to the main server/vhost configuration.